# TextInput Layout not clearing the error message

Tags: android

Text Fields errors not clearing after some user input.

If I add an error message it is positioned below the edit-text and everything looks good.

Here I entered first user name but error still displayed below the textinput layout.

[image]

Code:

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(display_name) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){

    mRegProgress.setTitle("Registering User");
    mRegProgress.setMessage("Please wait....");
    mRegProgress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    mRegProgress.show();

    register_user(display_name, email, password);

}else{

    if (mDisplayName.getEditText().getText().toString().length() == 0)
    {
        mDisplayName.setErrorEnabled(true);
        mDisplayName.setError("Please Provide Your Name!");
    }
    else if ((!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(mEmail.getEditText().getText().toString()).matches()) && mEmail.getEditText().getText().toString().length() == 0)
    {
        mEmail.setErrorEnabled(true);
        mEmail.setError("Please Provide Valid Email Address!");
    }
    else if (mPassword.getEditText().getText().toString().length() == 0)
    {
        mPassword.setErrorEnabled(true);
        mPassword.setError("Please Provide Password!");
    }

    else{
        if (mDisplayName.getEditText().getText().toString().length() > 0){
            mDisplayName.setError(null);
            mDisplayName.setErrorEnabled(false);
        }

        else if(mEmail.getEditText().getText().toString().length() > 0){
            mEmail.setError(null);
            mEmail.setErrorEnabled(false);
        }
        else if(mPassword.getEditText().getText().toString().length() == 0){
            mPassword.setError(null);
            mPassword.setErrorEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear your text input after you get their values - when you have confirmed they have values. If they have values nothing after the first else is executed.

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(display_name) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && 
!TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){

    mRegProgress.setTitle("Registering User");
    mRegProgress.setMessage("Please wait....");
    mRegProgress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    mRegProgress.show();

    register_user(display_name, email, password);
    // This is where you reset your text inputs and other bits and pieces.
    // If this is true nothing beyond here is executed!!

}else{
```

so move your logic above the else:

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(display_name) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && 
!TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){

    mRegProgress.setTitle("Registering User");
    mRegProgress.setMessage("Please wait....");
    mRegProgress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    mRegProgress.show();

    register_user(display_name, email, password);
    // This is where you reset your text inputs and other bits and pieces.
    // Start your logic to validate the input here
    if (mDisplayName.getEditText().getText().toString().length() == 0){
        .../...

}else{
    // Put your logic here if there is no input.
```